# responsive label and text output alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, multiple-columns

I have this html code that has a label and an output beside it.

```
<div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="head6">Business Name : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$name.'</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="head6">Website URL : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$url.'</span>    
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="head6">Tagline : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$tagline.'</span>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label class="head6">Description : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$descrip.'</span>    
                    </div>
```

and i have this css to control the output's distance from the label.

```
.halfR{
  width:60%;
  float:right;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

it looks fine when its on desktop view, the problem is when i re-size it to mobile size it becomes like this...

[image]

How can i solve this problem? It should be responsive. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Look into media queries, you will need to change your CSS properties at the mobile level. I would suggest making the labels and the spans both 100%, removing the float, so that the data shows under the labels. An alternative here would be to use display: table-cell and then simply change the widths in different media queries.

Comment: @Callum. is right. The issue you have in this case is that your labels are larger than 40%, hence causing a line break with your <span> that are 60% wide. Between media queries and table-cell layout, your call.

Comment: I still cant get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this  or use bootstrap tables http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

```
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="head6">Business Name : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$name.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="head6">Website URL : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$url.'</span>    
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="head6">Tagline : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$tagline.'</span>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="head6">Description : </label><span class="head9 halfR">'.$descrip.'</span>    
                </div>
```